# What is the value of GPG Passphrase for openstack-java-sdk in Windows 10

Tags: java, maven, openstack

After downloading the code from the following location:
https://github.com/woorea/openstack-java-sdk
and executing: mvn clean install. It prompts to enter"GPG Passphrase:"

What exactly is the input for the same?

Environment: Windows 10.

P.S.:: I tried installing the Gpg.exe in my system, then what do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is coming from the GPG plugin.  The documentation for that plugin says:

> Signs all of a project's attached artifacts with GnuPG.
>
> You need to have previously configured the default key.
>
> gpg also needs to be on the search path.

So ... the passphrase it is asking for is the passphrase for your default PGP signing key.

Looking at the `pom.xml` file, it looks like you should be able to call maven with `-Dskip.sign=true` to skip the JAR signing if you don't need this.  If you do need to sign the JAR, then configure the default key.  (Check the documentation that came with GPG.exe ....)